# How to fix slow image upload speed with Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

When uploading a 10.79 MB image from my application to Firebase Storage it takes about 6-8 seconds to complete which seems extremely long. Is it because the image is too large or am I doing something wrong in code? Here is my code:

```
func storeImage(pickedImage: Any){
    let username: String = Utilities.userAttributes.username
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let profileImageRef = storageRef.child("images/" + username + ".jpg")
    let imageData: Data = (pickedImage as! UIImage).pngData()!
    

    // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
    let uploadTask = profileImageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard metadata != nil else {
        print("error uploading")
        return
      }
    }
    
    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
      // Upload reported progress
      let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
        / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
      print(percentComplete)
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what about your wifi speed?

Comment: There's nothing in the code that you can do to make the upload go faster. Upload speed is based on protocol, bandwidth, and latency, not on any specific API call made (or not made) here.

Comment: I fixed it by compressing the image and saving it as a JPG rather than PNG. Its now around 1MB and uploads in a second

Answer (score 0):

Compressing the image and saving it as a new google format WEBP. (in my case 20X smaller image= 20X faster transfer)